# Gactions project is sending version 1 request schema

Tags: actions-on-google

According to this document [Actions on Google - Overview](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/migration)

Google is now using version 2 JSON schema, but the requests my server is receiving from the simulator is version 1. Is there something I need to do to get **version 2 JSON schema**?

I have updated my gactions project action.json file to the new format and uploaded it.

This is my `action.json`

```
{
"actions": [
    {
        "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
        "name": "MAIN",
        "fulfillment": {
            "conversationName": "welcome"
        },
        "intent": {
            "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
        }
    },
    {
        "description": "Example response",
        "name": "Raw input",
        "fulfillment": {
            "conversationName": "rawInput"
        },
        "intent": {
            "name": "raw.input",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "requestText",
                    "type": "SchemaOrg_Text"
                }
            ],
            "trigger": {
                "queryPatterns": [
                    "$SchemaOrg_Text:requestText"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"conversations": {
    "welcome": {
        "name": "welcome",
        "url": "https://myserver.com/api/request/gactions",
        "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    },
    "rawInput": {
        "name": "rawInput",
        "url": "https://myserver.com/api/request/gactions",
        "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you submitted the new action package for review?

Comment: No. My app is not deployed. I began making it right before version 2 was rolled out. I'm trying to get the initial app ready to be submitted and wanted to test it with my fulfillment servers first to make sure everything is working, but the schema is still version 1.

Comment: Does your action package explicitly set the version with fulfillmentApiVersion ?

Comment: I added my action.json above. Here is what I get when trying to upload it:
ERROR: Failed to update the app for the Assistant
ERROR: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fulfillment_api_version "
This page https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/migration says to use: fulfillment_api_version. I don't get an error when I use snake case, but it still doesn't work right.

Comment: It is fulfillmentApiVersion. We will fix the docs. What doesn't work right when you use that?

Comment: The action package uploads now, but I'm still getting the v1 from the simulator. Do I have to submit it before I can get version 2 schema or should it work at this point?

Also this gives a 404 from the migration page: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/action-package

Comment: We will fix that link. Yes, you have to re-submit to get the assistant platform to start using your v2 action package.

Comment: If there's an error on the fulfillment server and Google's testers are unable to complete the testing steps will my gactions project get rejected?

Comment: The review team will try out your action, so if the fulfillment fails, that will not allow them to complete their testing.

Comment: But I haven't been able to test version 2, since the simulator only sends version 1 schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator now sends version 2 and my application has not been approved yet. Here is what I get:

```
Request headers:
host: gactions.example.com
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
content-type: application/json
google-actions-api-version: 2
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
content-length: 380
x-forwarded-port: 443
x-forwarded-proto: https
x-forwarded-host: example.com
x-forwarded-server: ip-10-0-0-36.ec2.internal
connection: Keep-Alive
--------
Body of request: 
{
    "user": {
        "userId": "1500679128193",
        "locale": "en-US"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "1500679128193",
        "type": "NEW"
    },
    "inputs": [{
            "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN",
            "rawInputs": [{
                    "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
                    "query": "talk to tom's applicaiton"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "surface": {
        "capabilities": [{
                "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            }, {
                "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }
        ]
    },
    "device": {},
    "isInSandbox": true
}
```