# How can I get my gactions app approved?

Tags: actions-on-google

I've been trying to get my gactions app approved and haven't been successful. My app uses Oauth account linking. Included in this post is a screenshot of the rejection email, the request JSON I pulled from my fulfillment server, and the response JSON.

[image]

Google JSON request received by my fulfillment server:

```
{
    "isInSandbox": true,
    "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }
        ]
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "rawInputs": [
                {
                    "query": "talk to tom's app",
                    "inputType": "VOICE"
                }
            ],
            "arguments": null,
            "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN"
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "userId": "APhe68Ecie0lK5QZKEd9SWrXuN4w",
        "profile": null,
        "accessToken": null
     },
     "device": {
         "location": null
     },
     "conversation": {
         "conversationId": "1500420584998",
         "type": "NEW",
         conversationToken: null
     }
}
```

Response from fulfillment server:

```
{
    "conversationToken": "{"state":null,"data":{}}",
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "expectedInputs": [{
            "inputPrompt": {
                "initialPrompts": [{
                        "textToSpeech": "You must link your Google Assistant.",
                        "ssml": null
                    }
                ],
                "noInputPrompts": []
            },
            "possibleIntents": [{
                    "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
                    "inputValueData": {
                        "optContext": null,
                        "permissions": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "finalResponse": null
}
```

Is the above JSON response OK?

I'd really like to be able to test my app before submitting for approval, but I was told the simulator won't send version 2 schema until after my app is approved (see comments here: [Gactions project is sending version 1 request schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308005/gactions-project-is-sending-version-1-request-schema?noredirect=1#comment75842014_44308005)). Every time I submit for app approval it's like I'm shooting in the dark. Google doesn't give me detailed reasons why my app is failing.

What is the suggested way to test my app so I know it will get approved? How can I get more detailed information on why my app gets rejected?

Comment: The simulator is now sending version 2 schema. I created a test app without OAuth2 that works correctly. Seems the piece that breaks the simulator is OAuth2. I also verified my OAuth2 flow is valid via the Google OAuth2 Playground tool.

Comment: You are receiving the v2 (Proto3) request, you can tell from the camelCase syntax, so you should be able to test your app. Other than that, there might be a couple problems here. One is that you have double quotes within your conversationToken value, which is invalid JSON. The second is that you are using a SIGN_IN intent, which is only allowed if you've checked the "using Transactions API" box in the App Info section of the Actions Console. Is there any reason you're not using API.AI for this app?